# Arrayformula calculation with row()

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$4),5+row()-2,4,1,1)`

I'm looking to repeat the above formula in all row within the same column, so the calculation will change based on the `row()`. I tried to put it like below, column H is where the result will be going. But the `row()` is not following, all result are just using the formula row instead. The $A$4 is a where I'm using to input the range name.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(D3:D&OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$4),5+row()-3,4,1,1))`

I know I can drag it down, but automatic is always better. Before I'm over complicating the formula, is there a simple solution to make this work?

Updates:
Sample sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1di8a9I0Fv-vuQFDNfV3sPsnWbDuBWTNDYlvUAI5pOCk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @idfurw, it gives the result of the first row only, probably because it's inside the ```offset```

Comment: It works for me. `$A$4` should be something like `Sheet1!A1`.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know what data or data types are anywhere, what your layout is or what your end goal is. Consider sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet illustrating the problem, including manually typed results as you'd like to see them and where you would like to see them.

Comment: @idfurw, thanks for that, but I can't change $A$4 to Sheet1!A1, that part link to a named range, so changing that will have to change entire structure of the spreadsheet. I've add a sample sheet for your reference. Thanks

Comment: @ErikTyler, thank you, I just attached a sample spread sheet with link. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why don't simply use `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("CLASS_"&TO_TEXT($A$4)),5+row()-3,4)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with two formulas, each of which will return the same results:

`=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT("CLASS_"&$A$4),5+row()-3,4,COUNT(INDEX(INDIRECT("CLASS_"&$A$4))),1),"NO DATA")`

-or-

`=IFERROR(QUERY({INDEX(INDIRECT("CLASS_"&$A$4),,5)},"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null",0),"NO DATA")`

The D3 formula is better, because it is not dependent on the row where the formula is found (i.e., it can be placed anywhere and get the same result). It is "cleaner" (i.e., it has no redundancy of the INDIRECT clause). It's also easier to read and edit if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, Erik!

Comment: You're welcome.